# $\frac{\partial \mathbf{x}\mathbf{x}^{T}}{\partial \mathbf{x}}$ is this calculatable?

Tags: matrices, derivatives, vectors

I know $\frac{\partial \mathbf{x}^{T}\mathbf{x}}{\partial \mathbf{x}} = \mathbf{x}$, but what is the
$\frac{\partial \mathbf{x}\mathbf{x}^{T}}{\partial \mathbf{x}}$?
Is this calculatable? If it is, can anyone tell me how to derivative it? Thank you so much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\mathbf{x}\mathbf{x}^{\mathrm{T}}$ is the matrix $(x_ix_j)_{1\leq i, j\leq n}$ for $n$ the length of $\mathbf{x}$. Therefore, $\frac{\partial \mathbf{x}\mathbf{x}^{\mathrm{T}}}{\partial\mathbf{x}}$ will be the tensor $$\left(\frac{d}{dx_k} (x_ix_j)\right)_{1\leq i, j, k\leq n} = (\delta_{ik}x_j+\delta_{jk}x_i)_{1\leq i, j, k\leq n}$$ where $\delta_{xy}$ is the Kronecker delta.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I will check out tensor!

Answer (score 1):

Well to me the operator

$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial \textbf{x}}=\sum_{j=1}^{N}\hat{e}_j\frac{\partial}{\partial x_j}
$$

$$
\textbf{x}\textbf{x}^{T}=\sum_{m,n}\hat{e}_m\hat{e}_n x_m x_n
$$

$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial\textbf{x}}\textbf{x}\textbf{x}^{T}=\sum_{j,m,n}\hat{e}_j\hat{e}_m\hat{e}_n(x_n\frac{\partial x_m}{\partial x_j}+x_m\frac{\partial x_n}{\partial x_j})=
\sum_{j,m,n}\hat{e}_j\hat{e}_m\hat{e}_n(x_n\delta_{j,m}+x_m\delta_{j,n})=\sum_{m,n}(\hat{e}_m\hat{e}_m\hat{e}_n x_n+\hat{e}_n\hat{e}_m\hat{e}_n x_m)
$$

The object appears to be a rank three tensor.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer! I will check out tensor!